# Location of centromeres in humans

Tags: dna

I am creating a visual representation of which chromosome portions I inherited from each grandparent.  It would be helpful to include the centromere location as part of the visual representation, like FTDNA shows in its chromosome browser.  Where would I find a listing of the centromere locations for human chromosomes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ISOGG Wiki lists Centromere locations for Build 37 on [their Centromere page](https://isogg.org/wiki/Centromere).
[image]

Depending on what you're trying to match to, you may want to use Build 36.

Family Tree DNA uses Build 37 for matching but Build 36 for segment boundaries in their Chromosome browser. GEDmatch uses Build 36 for everything. See: ["Human reference genome" section of ISOGG CentiMorgan page](https://isogg.org/wiki/CentiMorgan).

Family Tree DNA [lists their Build 36 Centromere locations as](https://www.familytreedna.com/learn/autosomal-ancestry/universal-dna-matching/centromeres-located-autosomal-chromosome/):

[image]